# Server Promoted to Domain Controller causes high ping times

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, network-speed

We have recently (couple of months) been having issues with our internet, after dealing with our provider who states it is not their issue yet my boss and owner of the company is certain it is especially when we had our modem replaced and our ping times dropped from 300-600ms ping times down to 20-40ms ping times for 1 day (Friday) came back in on Monday and the ping times where high again.

Our network design is modem > asa5506 firewall router > TPlink switch >devices (cameras, phones, pc's, and server)
in process of troubleshooting with ISP they had me unplugging cables 1 at a time and when we unplugged the network cable or the Server the ping times increased.

I been going through the EV and resolving all critical and errors. I have ran dcdiag with tests passing. I eventually start killing each and every service 1 by 1 one night and found when I kill the ADDS the ping times increase. Confirmed with ISP to make sure they have no DNS, DHCP or firewalls running on the modem and that it is in bridged mode.

I removed the Windows 2016 Server from the domain and everything was pinging correctly. This is the only server on our network and we are a small company however instead of leaving it as a non domain controller my Boss wants Active Directory.

So to appease the boss I promoted the server back to Domain Controller and once I did our ping response increased to 300ms+ again.
No settings on the switch or router have changed.

I am banging my head against a brick wall trying to figure out what is cauing this cause even with out having any information put back into AD this issue came back. just the simple act of promoting to Domain Controller starts this entire problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tracert results

```
C:\Users\btreaster>tracert 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    75 ms    78 ms    61 ms  rrcs-24-73-252-193.se.biz.rr.com [24.73.252.193]

  2   348 ms     *        *     142.254.135.157

  3   303 ms   276 ms   272 ms  gig3-9.bumttxh10-rtr3.gt.rr.com [66.25.224.145]

  4     *      251 ms   261 ms  agg23.bumutx2801r.texas.rr.com [24.175.61.172]

  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  6   281 ms   320 ms     *     bu-ether16.hstqtx0209w-bcr00.tbone.rr.com [66.109.6.108]

  7     *      273 ms     *     107.14.19.49

  8   273 ms   264 ms   312 ms  0.ae1.pr1.dfw10.tbone.rr.com [107.14.17.234]

  9   276 ms     *      278 ms  ix-ae-23-0.tcore2.dt8-dallas.as6453.net [66.110.57.97]

 10     *      263 ms   262 ms  74.125.48.232

 11     *      274 ms   283 ms  108.170.252.161

 12   275 ms   271 ms     *     209.85.244.1

 13     *        *      296 ms  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Hi, please state what kind of ISP link you have, as if limited the windows update alone on the WS2016 could had took all your ISP bandwidth.

Comment: cable modem with spectrum business

Comment: spectrum business mean what ? 10m/10m, 10m/500k, etc...

Comment: but server is up todate, and again if I unplug the server the internet speed increases.... something keeps telling me it something in the DC Promotion process that is causing this but just can see what it is.

Comment: 100m/10m is our speed we pay for

Comment: DC promote dont do that, you can do it without internet. I suspect a download start, did you enabled WSUS at the same time ?

Comment: What are you pinging?

Comment: 8.8.8.8 pings return 300ms or above but everything internally and our external IP all return back normal ping times

Comment: I checked the services and saw WSUS server was running stopped it and ping times are still showing high

Comment: You're pinging the ip address 8.8.8.8? That's pretty strange. Run a tracert from a computer to 8.8.8.8 and post the results in your question.

Comment: added results to the question as per request

Comment: DC or not DC - doesn't matter, it doesn't do anything. Just check the network traffic (task manager, wireshark, mirror port ...).